# g++ not detected in VS Code

Tags: json, g++, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to compile c++ inside VS Code.
I have MinGW installed.
I've followed the steps in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFdJ68WbkdQ

And the steps at the "getting started" docs https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

Actually, my config shows like this:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "/usr/include",
            "/usr/local/include",
            "${workspaceRoot}"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "${workspaceRoot}"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        },
        "macFrameworkPath": [
            "/System/Library/Frameworks",
            "/Library/Frameworks"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "/usr/include",
            "/usr/local/include",
            "${workspaceRoot}"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "${workspaceRoot}"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/include/*",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/atlmfc/include/*",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.16299.0/um",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.16299.0/ucrt",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.16299.0/shared",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.16299.0/winrt",
            "${workspaceRoot}"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE"
        ],
        "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include\\c++",
                "C:\\MinGW\\bin"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    }
],
"version": 3
```

}

And the "tasks.json" file has the following:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "‪‪g++",
        "args": [
            "-g", "Calculator.cpp", "-o","Calculator"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "problemMatcher":"$gcc"
    }
]
```

}

But when I hit "run main task" it prompts:

"> Executing task: ‪‪g++ -g Calculator.cpp -o Calculator <

'‪‪g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1"

How can I get gcc detected?

I'm using VS Code with Windows 10 machine BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not added the folder path to windows, try that first.

If that still does not work try adding the full path in "task.json" instead of just g++.

Something like this:
C:/MinGW/bin/g++

Comment: It worked just with "g++", the conflict was at the environment variables(mismatching directories...), thank you so much!